# can you have multiple blogs in a confluence WIKI

Tags: blogs, confluence

it seems like there is only one global NEWS section per space.  is there anyway to have multiple blogs within confluence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each user has their own blogs, and you can create multiple spaces.  AFAIK, there isn't a way to have multiple news streams within one space.

Comment: what do you mean "each user has their own blogs".  how can that be setup ?

Comment: Click on any user name, and you will go to their space.  Then, under the Page menu, simply select 'News'.

Answer (score 2):

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-30105
According to the atlassian rep, "We've talked about this in the past before and concluded we don't have any plans on doing this in the foreseeable future".

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify - for a user to have their own blog they have to create their own personal space. With the most recent versions of Confluence (I think 3.1+) the word 'News' has been changed to 'Blog'.

Comment: @Brendan - but there is still no way to have multiple shared blogs on one space